# О вопросе "Почему выходит ошибка?"

Tags: javascript

Я вот думаю, когда в javascript не было стрелочных функций, можно было данную задачу решить  таким  образом?

```js
class Calc {
  constructor() {
    this.Plus = document.querySelector('.plus');
    this.Minus = document.querySelector('.minus');
    this.NumOne = document.getElementById('numone');
    this.NumTwo = document.getElementById('numtwo');
  }

  start() {
    this.Plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
      let NumOne = +calc.NumOne.value;
      let NumTwo = +calc.NumTwo.value;
      alert(NumOne + NumTwo);
    });
  }
}
let calc = new Calc;
calc.start();
```

Comment: Когда не было стрелочных, использовали bind, call, apply для привязки к контексту

Comment: Можете пояснить, как в данном коде использовать bind и т.д.?

Comment: См. Дубликат...

Comment: То, что теряется контекст это понятно. Вопрос,  какой объект передается в bind?

Comment: передаётся  `this`

Comment: Вы можете написать, как конкретно это выглядит в данном случае?

Comment: Здесь же получается, что методу calc.start мы должны передать при помощи функции bind объект calc. При этом, как мне кажется, происходит та же самая потеря контекста.

Comment: this - это ссылка на текущий объект ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да это все понятно. Можете написать строку кода, как это сделать?